# Two datacenters with one node in each datacenter

Tags: cassandra

In our organization, We are trying to have two cassandra dataceters with only 1 node on each side. From the preliminary investigation, I see replication is happening but I want to know if we can use this deployment in production? Will there be any performance issue with replication ?

We have already setup 2 datacenters with one node on each datacenter and replication is working fine.

Want to know if this kind of setup is recommended for production deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your use case is.

But in general multiple data centers for many reason:

1) Disaster recovery (DR).

2) To run different kind of load like analytics or search.

3) To decrease latency if your users are spread across the world.

In general minimum three nodes per data center is recommended in production. Again it depends on use case.